# How do I add a custom menu to hide/show two columns at the same time?

Tags: google-apps-script, menuitem

I have a sheet of statistics for a number of years; however, I want to hide future years to keep the table compact until those years are needed. I have the following script which hides and shows one column at a time but I need it to hide two at a time. For example, hide columns T and U on menu click (instead of just T on one click and U on the next click).

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Show Next Season')
      .addItem('Hide Columns', 'hideCol')
      .addItem("Show Columns", 'show')
      .addToUi();
}

function hideCol() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Season by Season'); //put the name of the sheet in place of 'Main'
  const array =  Array(sheet.getMaxColumns()-4).fill().map((element, index) => index + 20);
  for(let col of array){
     if(!sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(col)){
         sheet.hideColumns(col);
         break;
     }
  }
}

function show() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Season by Season'); //put the name of the sheet in place of 'Main'
  const array =  Array(sheet.getMaxColumns()-4).fill().map((element, index) => index + 20);
  for(let col of array){
     if(sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(col)){
         sheet.showColumns(col);
         break;
     }
  }
}
```

The script above only hides one column at a time. I'd like it to hide two at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
hideColumns(20,2);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. If I were to add the hideCol and show functions as a button, it only shows and hides the same two columns only. Any ideas how I can make this hide the first two columns starting at 20, then when those are hidden, click again for the next two, then next two, and so on?

Comment: Can you read the documentation for this command.  Go [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)  Use the search form at the top and type in hideColumns and read the documentation.   It's all there.

Comment: I have read the documentation on hideColumns. What I can't figure out is how to get the script to run consecutively. On the first click, it correctly hides columns T and U. But on second click, it does not do anything, when I'd like it to hide V and W. On third click, should hide X and Y. I am still trying to find the solution but am not an experienced coder so if anyone can help, it's appreciated.